C++/C kernel mode api/code for usermode app
Before describing the question itself, I will describe the essence of my project to make it easier for you to understand I have
how to add kernel api/code to user mode app
my application has these privileges to execute it
(so that this application can execute kernal code you need to make a usb flash drive create in it a folder EFI in it a folder boot with a file bootx64.efi, to get it compile the github project - https://github. com/ekknod/SubGetVariable, I have not tested on Intel processors and it works only with SECURE BOOT OFF and it was tested also only on windows 22h2 I DO NOT RECOMMEND YOU TO START THIS EFI FILE Just make sure USER MODE APPLICATION COMPILES AND STARTS).
For example my usermode app code:
main cpp (the code itself for usermode app):
#include “km.h”

//
// hello world
//

std::vector<QWORD> km::global_export_list;
NTOSKRNL_EXPORT(PsGetCurrentProcess);
NTOSKRNL_EXPORT(PsGetCurrentProcessId);

int main(void)
{
    if (!km::initialize())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    LOG(“current process: %llx\n”, km::call(PsGetCurrentProcess));
    LOG(“current process id: %lld\n”, km::call(PsGetCurrentProcessId));
}

km.h (responsible for communication between efi and user mode application for kernal code execution)
extern "C" NTSTATUS NTAPI RtlAdjustPrivilege(ULONG, BOOLEAN, BOOLEAN, PBOOLEAN);
extern "C" NTSTATUS NTAPI NtQuerySystemEnvironmentValueEx(PUNICODE_STRING, LPGUID, PVOID, PULONG, PULONG);

namespace km
{
    extern std::vector<QWORD> global_export_list;

    class DLL_EXPORT
    {
        QWORD address;
    public:
        DLL_EXPORT(QWORD address) : address(address)
        {
            global_export_list.push_back((QWORD)&this->address);
        }
        operator QWORD () const { return address; }
    };

    QWORD call(QWORD kernel_address, QWORD r1 = 0, QWORD r2 = 0, QWORD r3 = 0, QWORD r4 = 0, QWORD r5 = 0, QWORD r6 = 0, QWORD r7 = 0)
    {
        #pragma pack(push,1)
        typedef struct {
            QWORD param_1;
            QWORD param_2;
            QWORD param_3;
            QWORD param_4;
            QWORD param_5;
            QWORD param_6;
            QWORD param_7;
        } PAYLOAD ;
        #pragma pack(pop)

        PAYLOAD parameters;
        parameters.param_1 = r1;
        parameters.param_2 = r2;
        parameters.param_3 = r3;
        parameters.param_4 = r4;
        parameters.param_5 = r5;
        parameters.param_6 = r6;
        parameters.param_7 = r7;

        QWORD peb = __readgsqword(0x60);
        peb = *(QWORD*)(peb + 0x18);
        peb = *(QWORD*)(peb + 0x20);

        *(QWORD*)(peb + 0x18) = kernel_address;
        *(QWORD*)(peb + 0x10) = (QWORD)&parameters;

        UNICODE_STRING string;
        RtlInitUnicodeString(&string, L"SecureBoot");

        ULONG ret = 0;
        ULONG ret_len = 1;
        ULONG attributes = 0;

        GUID gEfiGlobalVariableGuid         = { 0x8BE4DF61, 0x93CA, 0x11D2, { 0xAA, 0x0D, 0x00, 0xE0, 0x98, 0x03, 0x2B, 0x8C }};
        NTSTATUS status = NtQuerySystemEnvironmentValueEx(&string,
                            &gEfiGlobalVariableGuid,
                            &ret,
                            &ret_len,
                            &attributes);

        QWORD rax = *(QWORD*)(peb + 0x18);
        *(QWORD*)(peb + 0x18) = 0;
        *(QWORD*)(peb + 0x10) = 0;

        if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
            return 0;

        return rax;
    }

    template <typename T>
    T call(QWORD kernel_address, QWORD r1 = 0, QWORD r2 = 0, QWORD r3 = 0, QWORD r4 = 0, QWORD r5 = 0, QWORD r6 = 0, QWORD r7 = 0)
    {
        QWORD ret = call(kernel_address, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7);
        return *(T*)&ret;
    }

    BOOL initialize(void)
    {
        QWORD ntoskrnl_base = 0;

        for (auto &drv : get_kernel_modules())
        {
            if (!_strcmpi(drv.name.c_str(), "ntoskrnl.exe"))
            {
                ntoskrnl_base = drv.base;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (ntoskrnl_base == 0)
        {
            LOG("ntoskrnl.exe base address not found\n");
            return 0;
        }

        for (auto &i : global_export_list)
        {
            QWORD temp = *(QWORD*)i;

            *(QWORD*)i = get_kernel_export(ntoskrnl_base, "ntoskrnl.exe", (PCSTR)temp);
            if (*(QWORD*)i == 0)
            {
                LOG("export %s not found\n", (PCSTR)temp);
                return 0;
            }
        }

        BOOLEAN privs=1;
        if (RtlAdjustPrivilege(22, 1, 0, &privs) != 0l)
        {
            LOG("run as admin\n");
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}


and I have also kernal code of another application and I want it to be executed in this application (hope I haven't confused you yet) also in C++ - -
https://github.com/danielkrupinski/KernelPID/blob/master/KernelPID/Driver.c
How can I compile my user mod app with the functions of this app when?
